# Intersection of hypersurfaces in the projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, intersection-theory

Fix an integer $n>0$. Is it true that for any $k>0$ and a closed point $x \in \mathbb{P}^n$, there exist hypersurface sections of degree $k$ (i.e., global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(k)$), say $Z_1,...,Z_m$ such that $Z_1 \cap Z_2 \cap ... \cap Z_m=\{x\}$? Note that I am not putting any constraint on $m$.

Comment: This is true if you are thinking clasically, not scheme-theoretically. Let $\mathfrak m$ be the maximal ideal of your point $x$ and let $\mathfrak m^k = (f_1,\ldots,f_m)$. The $f_i$ are homogeneous of degree $k$ and each of them defines a hypersurface $Z_i$. Then, $Z_1\cap\cdots\cap Z_m=Z(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=Z(\mathfrak m^k)=Z(\mathfrak m)=\{x\}$.

Comment: As an illustration of @Jesko's excellent comment, we have $\{(1:0:0:...:0)\}=V(x^k_2,...,x_{n+1}^k)$

Comment: If you take an arbitrary closed point, it is not even clear that there exists a single hypersurface of degree $k$ containing it. On the other hand, if you are working over, say an algebraically closed field, this is always true even scheme theoretically- of course $m$ can be large.